# Swagger not showing my controllers. Tried Postman, my endpoints still failling

Tags: java, sql-server, swagger, postman, endpoint

Hope you're all doing great. I'm trying to code API's with Java and Springboot as my framework. I'm using sqlServer as my database. I did the whole configuration to make the connection possible (enabled tcp/ip protocols, got sql servers up, used an sql server jar file and dll file in my project, allowed remote connections with sql server). When i execute a query in my project in works and shows me the data in the console. BUT, when I use Swagger, there isn't my User controllers and it's methods, it just brings the basic error controller.

[image]

I have the swagger dependencies in my pom file, and I have the @EnableSwagger2 in my main application.

This is what happens when I use postman:

[image]

I don't know what to do, I can't try my API's.

Here u can see my user controller:

```
import JDBC.DAO.UsuarioDAO;
import JDBC.DTO.Usuario;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
public class UsuarioResource {

   //Get usuario por rut
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "traerUsuario/{rut}")
    public List<Usuario> obtenerUsuarioPorRut (@PathVariable ("rut") String rut) throws SQLException {
        List<Usuario> user = new UsuarioDAO().obtenerUsuarioPorRut(rut);
        return user;
    }

    //Get todos los usuarios
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "allUsers")
    public List <Usuario> getUsuarios() throws SQLException {
        List <Usuario> usuarios = new UsuarioDAO().obtenerUsuarios();
        return usuarios;
    }


}
```

You can see my url should be localhost:8080/whateverendpointgoeshere (When I run my application it says running op port 8080).

This is the ConnectionManager I made to, uh, connect to the database (It works because as I said before, it brings me data when I do it directly in my IDE):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionManager {
    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databasename=prac; integratedSecurity=true";

    public static Connection obtenerConexion() throws SQLException {
        if (connection == null)
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            return connection;
    }
}
```

In this image you can see why I'm using port 1433 to connect to sql server, I'm following what the TCP/IP says:

[image]

Swagger dependencies in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

So... I've been stuck for some days trying to figure out why I can't hit my endpoints. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have some class-related with the configuration of Swagger? Something like "SpringFoxConfig" which mention here https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api. More of the problems related to Swagger is connected with the package to scan

Comment: I've tried that... But it didn't work out. The weird thing is that I already used springboot, java and swagger in another computers without any extra configurations with no problems, but in this pc I can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: Could you add your "Main" class with all the annotations related to @SpringBootApplication, @ComponentScan?

Comment: Thank u! It was something related to this. I finally fixed it thanks to the answer below. I appreciare your time. It was a rookie mistake that I will keep in mind from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since you can't access the endpoints even without swagger, this is an issue with your package structure. Your controller package and all other component packages (eg. service, repository) should be a subpackage under the package your main class (SpringBootApplication.java) is in. (If not a subpackage of your main class's package, you need to manually add them in @ComponentScan annotation.)

Comment: It was a problem with the structure. Thank you so much! You really helped me out.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You need have configuration file for Swagger in spring boot.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

Annotate the class with `@Configuration` . You can leave the rest same as above .

Restarting the server and hitting swagger URL should fix it .